# Converting String Format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ" to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I know this question has been asked a number of different ways, and I have looked at them all and none of the solutions seem to work for me. So, I am hoping that maybe you guys can give me a quick hand.

The input string is: "2000-01-01T12:00:000Z". I need to take that input string and convert it to DateTime so that it can be stored in the database.

I have been using ParseExact, but I keep getting the not recognized date string exception. Where am I going wrong?

```
inValue.LatestDepartTime = "2000-01-01T12:00:000Z";
DateTime _latestDepartTime = DateTime.ParseExact(inValue.LatestDepartTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your format string needs to **exact**ly match the input.

That includes the literal `T` and `Z` characters.

Comment: So, I should be able to parse out the T and Z from the original string which should give me: 2020-01-01 12:00:000. Then the two strings will match exactly. But, I have tried this and still get the same error. One thing to note, and perhaps this will help, in debugging i noticed that the _latestDepartTime is set to 1/1/0001 12:12:000 AM each time I tried this.

Comment: No; you need to include the `T` and `Z` in the format string.  You may need to wrap them in single quotes; I don't remember.

Comment: You're just seeing the default (empty) value of a `DateTime`.

Comment: I got it to work. What I needed to do was parse out the T and Z because what I wanted is a date that SQL Server 2008 can store in its DateTime format (i.e. 2000-01-01 12:00:00.000). However, my issue was partly an ID10T error cause in testing I was inputting a string "2000-01-01T12:00.000Z" which was all wrong. It should have been "2000-01-01T12:00:00.000Z". Otherwise you were right on, the two strings needed to be exactly alike and that was where I was having my issue. I didn't understand ParseExact from the MSDN literature, so was a little confused. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should be using parameters; SQL Server shouldn't know or care about string formatting.

Comment: May you explain please? How do you use parameters when the input is not in the valid "DateTime" format?

Comment: @CalvinBlount: Parse the string to a DateTime (this step has nothing to do with SQL), then pass the `DateTime` value as a parameter (this step has nothing to do with strings)

Answer (score 9):

Use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'`

The code is:

```cs
public DateTime convertIsoToDateTime (string iso)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(iso, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to include `\\T` and `\\Z` in your format string to match the literals `T` and `Z`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify the `T` in the pattern.

That said, you may want to have a look at the `XmlConvert` class, which provides the methods for converting this format.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put single quotes around the T and Z:

```
DateTime parsedDateTime;
DateTime.TryParseExact(obj, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDateTime);
return parsedDateTime;
```